# jupyterでファイルを書き込もうとしたらpermisson deniedエラーが出た

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebookで下のコードを実行しようとしたら、14行目でpermission deniedエラーがでました。調べてもピンとくるものがなかったのですが、どうしたらいいですか。

## 環境

- OS

  - Windows 10
- Jupyter notebookはedgeで開いています。

```py
import gzip 
file=[
    "train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz",
    "train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz",
    "t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz",
    "t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz"
]

for f in file:
    raw_file= "/"+f.replace(".gz","")
    with gzip.open(f,"rb") as gz:
        body = gz.read()
        with open(raw_file,"wb") as raw_w:
            raw_w.write(body)
```

Comment: このソースコードはUnix系環境用の者に見えます。 `raw_file= "/"+f.replace(".gz","")` の `"/"` を`"C:\` に書き換えて再度実行してみてください。

Comment: Ｃドライブ直下ではなく、同ディレクトリ内にしたかったので"/"を消したら、直りました。サーブレットの癖で書いてしまっていました。

Answer (score 0):

コメントから相対ディレクトリの指定が間違っていたことに気づきました。

./かファイル名のみでよかったのでした。